Unable to print 2nd occurrence from rates
My sample text is pretty simple
$56K - $86K (glass

My regex is
[0-9]+K

which prints both 56K and 86K but I just want to print out 86K i.e. the 2nd time it matches the regex.
I have tried the following but it didn't work, please can you tell me what I am doing wrong here
[0-9]+K{2}


